# Xamarin Forms Deploy error Could not load assembly 'System.Memory'

Tags: xamarin.forms

**Xamarin Forms Android**

Some recent nuget package level is causing this error.
We we only using stable packages, but I started trying more recent Xamarin pre- release packages to see if the issue has been resolved.

The part of the Build and Debug Output with error.

**Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Memory'.**
07-06 10:10:51.972 F/monodroid-assembly( 4029): Could not load assembly 'System.Memory' during startup registration.

The Compile is set to use Latest(8.1)
Minimum version is 7.0

From other posts, i tried deleting shared runtime and tried the Android options with and with used shared runtime checked.

**edit 3: Updated output from Debug:**

07-06 10:10:48.375 D/Mono    ( 4029): AOT: image '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC-xDHzK4ivf73vZ_mvi0X4Jg==/lib/x86/libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.so" not found
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC-xDHzK4ivf73vZ_mvi0X4Jg==/lib/x86/libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.so" not found
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll'.
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.config'.
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Xamarin.Forms.Platform/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.config'.
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll'.
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Image addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xcbf3d2c0] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll[0xcbf50400]: 2
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Prepared to set up assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll)
07-06 10:10:48.376 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xcbf3d2c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
07-06 10:10:48.377 D/Mono    ( 4029): AOT: image '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC-xDHzK4ivf73vZ_mvi0X4Jg==/lib/x86/libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.so" not found
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC-xDHzK4ivf73vZ_mvi0X4Jg==/lib/x86/libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.so" not found
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll'.
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.config'.
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.config'.
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/System.Memory.dll'.
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Image addref System.Memory[0xcbf3d4a0] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/System.Memory.dll[0xcbf50e00]: 2
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Image for assembly 'System.Memory' (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/System.Memory.dll) has ReferenceAssemblyAttribute, skipping
07-06 10:10:48.378 D/Mono    ( 4029): Unloading image /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/System.Memory.dll [0xcbf50e00].
07-06 10:10:48.379 D/Mono    ( 4029): Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/local/lib/System.Memory.dll'.Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Oxando.OxandoXPC/files/.**override**/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll [External]
...
...
Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Memory'.
07-06 10:10:51.972 F/monodroid-assembly( 4029): Could not load assembly 'System.Memory' during startup registration.
07-06 10:10:51.972 F/monodroid-assembly( 4029): This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
07-06 10:10:51.972 F/monodroid-assembly( 4029): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.

Comment: Have you tried to: Delete bin/obj folders. Uninstall the application from the emulator/phone, restart visual studio, in android options->cancel " use shared runtime " ?

Comment: Hi Bruno, looks like your idea may have resolved one issue. It now bombs elsewhere :(

Comment: I have tried ideas. System deploy problem with System.Memory

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you try this Go to android Project>Right the Properties>Go to Android options>Advanced>In supported architecture tick all and set Java max Heap Size to 1 G if that not working can you try this 


This seemed to work for me. I will have to do more testing when I get time. Found it on the EF Core git bug lists.

Manually edit your csproj file and define, that the NU1605 warning shouldn't be treated as an error.

<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1605</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
Now in your Project File add the Package:

<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.3.0" />
Then I would:

Clean the NuGet Caches
Clean all bin and obj folders
Restore the Packages
Build
```

Comment: x86 is in the list of supported Architectures, i set 1G to Max heap size.  im The result is the original error again.

Comment: im still testing your suggestion. including the package unsafe manually IM getting conflicts and the error  Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'. perhaps the version isnt right

Comment: You can add latest from nuget package

Comment: with the latest nuget version ofComplierServices.Unsafe (4.5.1) it is now back at Could not load assembly 'System.Memory' during startup registration.

Comment: thanks for trying Adit, but it looks like this did get system.Memory loaded.